# Using ReplaySubject in Angular at PUT Request it is losing the data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am having an issue with the `ReplaySubject`, I don't know what I have done wrong but the problem it is that when I change something and save it in backend, the `ReplaySubject` it calls new data but it is hiding them to show me see the picture.
I tried to use `detectChanges` but without any luck, but as i know the `detectChanges` will work only when we have `parent` -> `child` iterration.

This happens on update
[image: This happens when I update]

This happens when I reload the page
[image: This is when I reload]

If I remove the the `this.data.next(res)` at this line of the `Put Request` then it works but I need again to reload page to get new data.

```
 return this.http.put(api, dataModel).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
```

This is the code of the service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ModelDataService {
  public baseUrl = environment.backend;
  private data = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  public userID = this.authService.userID;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {
  }

   public getJSON() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data/${this.userID}`).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  public dataModel(): Observable<any> {
    return this.data.asObservable();
  }
  public setData(data: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data`;
    const user_id = this.authService.userID;
    this.http.post(api, data, {
      headers: {user_id}
    }).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }

  public updateDate(id: string, dataModel: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(api, dataModel).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }
}
```

This is the component.

```
 public model$: Observable<Model>;
 public model: Model;


 constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private modelDataService: ModelDataService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getUserProfile(this.userID).subscribe((res) => {
      this.currentUser = res.msg;
    });
    this.modelDataService.getJSON();
    this.model$ = this.modelDataService.dataModel();
    this.model$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.model = data; // here if i try to console log then I have the array but the page it will be blank
    console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

And then for example I try to show data like this.

```
   <ng-container class="Unit-unit-unitGroup" *ngFor="let personalData of model.personalData; let id = index">
</ng-container>
```

In the `put` Request I have added an console log and this is what I am getting.
[image: Pic3]

But on reload I am getting I think another way of strucuter of data.
See picture[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ng-container class="Unit-unit-unitGroup" *ngFor="let personalData of model.personalData; let id = index">
</ng-container>

this.model$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.model = data; // here if i try to console log then I have the array but the page it will be blank
    console.log(data);
    });

public updateDate(id: string, dataModel: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(api, dataModel).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
  }
```

You expect `personalData` to be a property of your model. However, as seen in the console log your `res` is an object including `data` as an object between. All you need to do is mapping `res` to it's `data`.

```
public updateDate(id: string, dataModel: Model) {
    const api = `${this.baseUrl}/data/${id}`;
    return this.http.put(api, dataModel).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res.data));
  }
```

Comment: it will not working because it will come an error.
`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

Comment: Should be a type issue. Please add any type `this.http.put<any>` or even better, a real type

Comment: it is working but it is adding the data twice now in backend ?

Comment: I mean only when I edit some data it is adding twice, in new data it is working good.

Answer (score 2):

Use ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes again in the view when the data comes back.

```
this.model$.subscribe((data) => {
  this.model = data;
  this.cd.detectChanges();
});
```